# Magento 2 di.xml reuse array arguments

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, di

In Magento 2 di.xml we can inject an array to a class like this:

```xml
<type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Foo">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="item1" xsi:type="string">Item 1</item>
      <item name="item2" xsi:type="string">Item 2</item>
    </argument>
  <arguments>
</type>
```

How can we inject the same `data` array to another class `Vendor\Module\Model\Bar` without duplicating it like this?

```xml
<type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Bar">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="item1" xsi:type="string">Item 1</item>
      <item name="item2" xsi:type="string">Item 2</item>
    </argument>
  <arguments>
</type>
```

VirtualType only works for objects, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class like "ItemList" and assign the array as argument. Then you use ItemList in both your classes "Foo", "Bar".